# Parse json with Objects to model Object - Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have model:

```
public class StudyModel {
    @Id
    private String ID;
    private boolean isStable;
    private String LastUpdate;
    private MainTest test;

    public static class MainTest {
        private String test1;
        private String test2;
    }
}
```

I want to parse it to my model.
It works correctly but when it goes to `MainTest` where on json file I have couple values it fails and I have null on the rest of fields.
How I can deal with it?

```
public StudyModel getStudyDetails(String studyId){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = URL + "studies/" + studyId;
        ResponseEntity<String> serverResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
        Gson g = new Gson();
        String json = serverResponse.getBody();
        StudyModel study = g.fromJson(json, StudyModel.class);

        return study;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the class have to match the type? `StudyRadiology study = g.fromJson(json, StudyModel.class)` Does `StudyRadiology` extend `StudyModel`?

Comment: You can answer your own question. Just put your "update" in an answer below.

Comment: Please add your answer in answer section and not by editing question

Answer (score 1):

RestTemplate can handle deserialization for you

```
ResponseEntity<StudyModel> serverResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, StudyModel.class);
StudyModel studyModel = serverResponse.getBody();
```